# How to customize the look and feel of django admin

Tags: python, django

How to customize the look and feel of django admin?

Comment: what do you mean with "Even table is not getting created"? When rewrite the admin interface, you rewrite an interface, not a table.

Answer (score 1):

You should create ModelAdmin classes to customize the django admin site.

See this page in the django book for details:

http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter06/

Answer (score 1):

try [Django Grappelli](http://code.google.com/p/django-grappelli/)

Bye!

Answer (score 0):

Have you set up the tables in the DB yet? As per http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/intro/tutorial01/?

Answer (score 0):

1) ModelAdmin, you can customize the Forms for CRUD operations with this.
2) Overload your Admin Templates 
3) Admin Tools and Grappelli provide great options to extend and customize the Django Admin

sorry, i can't post links but google can help easily with 1) and 2) searchs.